# How to dynamically add HTTP headers in CXF client?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm using `Spring` and `CXF` to create a soap webservice client.

The webservice requires the HTTP header `Authorization=[pass]` for authentication. So far I implemented it as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> context = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Basic pass")); //fixed value so far
context.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```

But now I have to change the basic pass dynamically based on the user that actually executes the client.

Problem: as I use CXF with Spring, my CXF clients are managed and shared proxies by Spring.
So whenever I change the HTTP header inside the `port`, it will affect all the instances!

How could I add the HTTP auth header dynamically just during sending of the webservice requests?

I have to exactly create a http header lik: `Authorization=[pass]`

Answer (score 4):

I assume what you really want to do is HTTP BASIC Authentication. There are defined APIs in CXF to set username/password for BASIC authentication. This will do what you want:

```
HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(stub).getConduit();
httpConduit.getAuthorization().setUserName("username");
httpConduit.getAuthorization().setPassword("password");
```

There are also other alternatives, like putting username/password directly into the request context:

```
AuthorizationPolicy authzPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
authzPolicy.setUserName("username");
authzPolicy.setPassword("password");
((BindingProvider) stub).getRequestContext().put(AuthorizationPolicy.class.getName(), authzPolicy);
```

Comment: This will change the HTTP header statically in the proxy request context. Which works for a single user, but not dynamically threadsafe. If you have a threadsafe solution, eg a http header that is added dynamically to the xml request, let me know.

Comment: Anyways your solution using `AuthorizationPolicy` should probably be the preferred way for implementing basic authorization, instead of manually constructing the http header. thanks for this.

Comment: @membersound   I was trying to get the same behavior in a thread-safe manner. Now am using interceptor on client object for this which is not thread-safe and lead to issues. Because of that I will need to create a port each and every time. If you have anything useful related to this then please do share.

Comment: @Sachin it's almost 3 yrs ago so I can't remember exactly. But I don't think it was possible. I created a lazy "port cache" with assigned credentials. So you have to create a new port for each different credential pair you'd be using, but instantiate only on first access and cache it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should config Spring to work with each user in own session, so client instance will be different for every user. And for client instance you could do something similar:

```
Client proxy = ClientProxy.getClient(stub);

// Creating HTTP headers
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
headers.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Basic pass"));

// Add HTTP headers to the web service request
proxy.getRequestContext().put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
```

Comment: But that will add a `soap:header` element, right? What I need is a HTTP header element that is exactly named "Authorization", so that the `Authorization=[Basic pass]` http header is created. Whereas the "basic pass" has to be `base64(username:password)` encoded string by design of the soap service. I think that's not possible with httpconduit, isn't it?

Comment: what about new version? =)

Comment: This will change the HTTP header statically in the proxy request context. Which works for a single user, but not dynamically  threadsafe.